# Google vr view using click on hotspot to change content

Tags: google-vr

Once I have an embedded vr view on my website, how do I implement clicking on a hotspot?

```
function onVrViewLoad() {

var v;

v = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
    image: '/images/firstImage.jpg',
    is_stereo: false
});

v.on('ready', function(){
    v.addHotspot('hotspotOne', {
        pitch: 0, // In degrees. Up is positive.
        yaw: 180, // In degrees. To the right is positive.
        radius: 0.05, // Radius of the circular target in meters.
        distance: 2 // Distance of target from camera in meters.
    });
});

v.on('click', function(event) {
    if (event.id == 'hotspotOne') {
        v.setContentInfo({
            image: '/images/secondImage.jpg',
            is_stereo: false
        });
    }
});}
```

The hotspot shows up and can be clicked, but it does not change the image. If I replace the v.setContentInfo() to window.location.href='/secondImage.html' where I have set up another vr viewer with that image, it loads the page. So I know the click event is registering correctly, but the setContentInfo() is not.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the documentation says to use setContentInfo(), I've found it's actually setContent() that works. This gave me a headache for a while!

```
v.setContent({
    image: '/images/secondImage.jpg',
    is_stereo: false
});
```